# Show pull requests on GitHub regarding a specific file or line

Tags: github

Let's assume I found a typo in some project's file.  The project has a lot of open pull requests¹, so it's not practical to manually search through the pull requests to see if any of them contain a fix for this typo.

Is there a way to see all pull requests that change the regarding file, or better yet the regarding line?

¹ E.g., take [Docker](https://github.com/docker/docker/pulls), which has 98 open pull requests at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hopefully by now you've found an answer to your question, but if not (or if anyone else has the same question) you can search a repo's open pull requests for a word or phrase -- the file name, for example, or the typo corrected, or the line that it appears on.

To search open pull requests, use the following search query:

`is:pr is:open "phrase to search for"`

Searching the [Docker pull requests](https://github.com/docker/docker/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr%20is%3Aopen%20%22fix%20typo%22%20) for "fix typo" right now returns 1 result.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach is not entirely reliable where specification of the name of a file is _exact_. Please see <https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/36946#discussioncomment-3945223> under **find PRs that update a file · Discussion #36946 · community**.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me for finding PRs touching a specific file, in my case file path: `client/src-shared/TgSequenceEditor`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little script I cobbled together to solve a similar issue:

```
#grab all the PRs and sort them so the newest ones are first in the list:
git ls-remote origin 'pull/*/head' | awk '{print $2}' | grep -oE '[0-9]+' | sort -n | tail -r |
#read each PR and filter for any that have changed file in question 
while read pr; do
  echo "Searching $pr"
  if gh pr view $pr --json files --jq '.files.[].path' | grep -q "yourFileNameHere"; then
    echo "Found in PR $pr - $(gh pr view $pr --json state --jq '.state')" 
  fi
done
```

(btw you'll need the github cli tool gh - https://cli.github.com/)